# Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: solidity

This is my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "./ERC721Tradable.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC721Tradable {
    string apiUrl;

    constructor(address _proxyRegistryAddress)
        ERC721Tradable("MyContract", "MyToken", _proxyRegistryAddress)
    {
        apiUrl = "https://morning-woodland-24255.herokuapp.com/nftart/";
    }

    function baseTokenURI() public view override returns (string memory) {
        return apiUrl;
    }

    function setBaseTokenURI(string memory _apiUrl) public onlyOwner {
        apiUrl = _apiUrl;
    }
}
```

The `setBaseTokenURI(string memory _apiUrl)` setter works , however the `baseTokenURI()` does not.

I deploy my contract on ganache and then I try to run it:

```
hijackedStack: "Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.\n" +
    '    at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (/Users/luciantarna/.nvm/versions/node/v16.4.2/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:297:1)\n' +
    '    at ABICoder.decodeParameters
```

I tried reinstalling web3 but that seemed to not have helped and to revert my migrations, so I guess my code is broken somehow ?

These are my dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.2.0",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "pify": "^5.0.0",
    "web3": "^1.5.1"
  }
```

Edit: It happens because of the "view" keyword. Why is it not ok? If I remove it, it works.

Edit 2: I am just trying to follow the opensea tutorial, but it seems their contract doesn't work:

https://docs.opensea.io/docs/1-structuring-your-smart-contract

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/style-guide.html?highlight=function#function-declaration) say  (near:  "The modifier order for a function  should be:")  that `view` should be mentioned before `override`

Comment: You could always raise the issue on their Github page: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/issues

Comment: I have found no solution to locally make it work but it works on rinkeby. This is a surprising turn of events as now I can say: but it works on production.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/style-guide.html?highlight=function#function-declaration):

The modifier order for a function should be:

- Visibility
- Mutability
- Virtual
- Override
- Custom modifiers

Yes:

```
function balance(uint from) public view override returns (uint)  {
    return balanceOf[from];
}

function shutdown() public onlyOwner {
    selfdestruct(owner);
}
```

No:

```
function balance(uint from) public override view returns (uint)  {
    return balanceOf[from];
}

function shutdown() onlyOwner public {
    selfdestruct(owner);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/contracts/ERC721Tradable.sol#L66

why does this work then ?... :( let me try your suggestion

Comment: It seems the issue still stands sadly :(